# how to upload ipa on xamarin test cloud using command line

Tags: xamarin

I'm getting this error  on Xamarin Forms app with I "Run in Test Cloud". 
The Android project / UITest uploads and runs fine using "Run in Test Cloud". but ios / UITest give error Unknown MSBuild failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload ipa file using command line:-

link : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/submitting-tests-at-command-line/